# Not able to draw vertical event lines for morris chart

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I'm trying to include event lines in the Morris line chart. The event lines appear for integer values in the X axis but not for time values. It just draws an event line for '00:00:00' when event values are passed and `parseTime` parameter is set to true and nothing appears when `parseTime` is set to `false`. So basically, how can I draw events for time values on the X axis ?

```
var morrisLineData = [{y: "11:16:02", a: 17.73},
                {y: "11:16:53", a: 39.43},
                {y: "11:16:58", a: 5.02},
                {y: "11:17:07", a: 17.73}];
var morrisLine = Morris.Line({ 
    resize: true,
    element: 'morrisLine',
    data: morrisLineData,
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: 'a',
    labels: ['value1'],
    xLabelAngle: 45, 
    gridTextSize: 12,  
    parseTime: true, 
    hideHover: true,
    lineColors: ['#0088cc'], 
    events: ['11:16:58'],
    eventLineColors: 'black'
});
morrisLine.setData(morrisLineData);
```